# How to represent a number as a list of sums? (Or How to stack up or fill given number into categories based on a given list?)

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two set of lists:
first list (let us call it A) `{121, 30, 70, 50}` and
a second, list of list (call it B)
`{{90,10,30},{40,20,1},{10,70,20},{10,15,20}}`
Following operations need to be performed to get the output list:

1. take the first element of list A and take first list of list B, in this case `121` and `{90,10,30}`
2. `121` can be divided or stacked (or filled) as `90+10+21=121` based on the list `{90,10,30}`, here full of `90` is used then full of `10` is used then only `21` of `30` is used. So the output for first value is `{90,10,21}` (Note: Elements are stacked from Left to right, ie., 10 starts filling only after 90 is fully filled and 30 starts filling only after 10 is fully filled)

   - similarly for the second items `30` and `{40,20,1}` only `30` out of `40` is enough and then nothing of the others so, `0` of `20` and `0` of `1`, so the output is `{30,0,0}` such that `30+0+0=30`
   - For the third items `70` and `{10,70,20}` full `10` out of `10` is used and then `60` of `70` and `0` of `20`, so the output is `{10,60,0}` such that `10+60+0=70`
   - For the fourth items `50` and `{10,15,20}` full `10` out of `10` is used and then full `15` of `15` and full `20` of `20`, so the output is `{10,15,20}` such that `10+15+20=45`. **NOTE:** 45 is less than 50 but that is not a problem. The aim is to fully use the list to the maximum possible amounts from Left to Right and try to come close or satisfy the number.
3. Some Notes:
   Numbers can be float. Integers are given here for only example and explanation purpose.
   The size of the lists inside list B will all be the same, in this case 3 elements.
   The size of the list A and corresponding B is much larger (around 8670 items) than shown in the example.
   **Summary**:
   Inputs: `{121, 30, 70, 50}` ; `{{90,10,30},{40,20,1},{10,70,20},{10,15,20}}`
   Output:  `{{90,10,21},{30,0,0},{10,60,0},{10,15,20}}`

Fun Fact: This logic is used in real life to dispatch power plants to supply electricity demand and it is called **stack dispatch model**. List A is the demand at a given hour, and list B are power plants available at that hour. Output is how much of each power plant is operated to satisfy the demand.

I am looking for a simple and efficient code for this operation. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g = Differences @ Prepend[0] @ Clip[Accumulate @ #2, {0, #}] &;

MapThread[g] @ {a, b}
```

> ```
> {{90, 10, 21}, {30, 0, 0}, {10, 60, 0}, {10, 15, 20}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a first attempt:

```
a = {121, 30, 70, 
  50}; 
b = {{90, 10, 30}, {40, 20, 1}, {10, 70, 20}, {10, 15, 20}}
```

Define function:

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{w},
  w = SplitBy[FoldList[Subtract, x, y], Sign][[1]];
  ArrayReshape[-Differences@Append[w, 0], 3, 0]
  ]
```

Apply to data:

```
MapThread[f, {a, b}]
```

yields:

> {{90, 10, 21}, {30, 0, 0}, {10, 60, 0}, {10, 15, 20}}

Answer (score 3):

Finally, got the chance to use [`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) :D - Even though the solution below is simpler, it's a little slower than @ubpdqn's answer:

Define the function

```
ClearAll[temp];

temp[n_, values_] := FoldPairList[{Min[##], #1 - Min[##]} &, n, values];
```

Apply to data

```
MapThread[temp, {a, b}]

(* Out: {{90, 10, 21}, {30, 0, 0}, {10, 60, 0}, {10, 15, 20}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {121, 30, 70, 50};
b = {{90, 10, 30}, {40, 20, 1}, {10, 70, 20}, {10, 15, 20}};

accumulateWhile[{a_Integer, b_List}] :=
 Differences@FoldList[If[#1 + #2 <= a, #1 + #2, a] &, 0, b]

accumulateWhile /@ Transpose[{a, b}]
```

> {{90, 10, 21}, {30, 0, 0}, {10, 60, 0}, {10, 15, 20}}

Answer (score 2):

```
 a = {121, 30, 70, 50};
b = {{90, 10, 30}, {40, 20, 1}, {10, 70, 20}, {10, 15, 20}};
Transpose@Ramp[# - Ramp[Accumulate@# - Threaded@a]] &@Transpose@b
```

> ```
> {{90, 10, 21}, {30, 0, 0}, {10, 60, 0}, {10, 15, 20}}
> ```

```
n = 10^6;
a = RandomReal[{1, 100}, n];
b = RandomReal[{100, 200}, {n, 3}];

f = Transpose@Ramp[#2 - Ramp[Accumulate@#2 - Threaded@#1]] &;
g = Differences@Prepend[0]@Clip[Accumulate@#2, {0, #}] &;

r1 = MapThread[g]@{a, b}; // RepeatedTiming
r2 = f[a, Transpose@b]; // RepeatedTiming
r1 == r2
```

> ```
> {2.84142, Null}
> {0.047036, Null}
> True
> ```